# Javascript client-side framework not conflict with django template language

Tags: angularjs, ember.js, django-templates, javascript-framework

First, [django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/) is used on server-side to publish the static html pages.

Within the HTML pages, I am trying to find some client-side javascript framework which can provide some sort of structure (MVC, MVP, MVVM, MVW. ect.)

[AngularJS](http://code.angularjs.org/), [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/), [Soma.js](http://somajs.github.io/somajs/), they conflict with the Django template language

[Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) seems is the only choice so far. any more suggestions? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angularJS works fine with django template language with one simple change.

The $interpolateProvider service controls the interpolation symbols, which can be changed, angularjs use of {{}} is just a default.

```
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolateProvider
```

To change the symbols, to say '{[{}]}', its simply:

```
 app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
 $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you and a look at anything that Toran https://github.com/toranb is doing with django and ember?  He is great and a wonderful teacher. Here is a link to a django ember example https://github.com/toranb/ember-django-rest. Here is a video about ember with a django backend. http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/01/03/Intro-to-ember-js-and-the-new-router-api/

I hope this is helpful.

Cheers
Dave

Comment: Thank you, I only use django template in .NET, seems not suitable for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template delimiters in Soma-template easily using the settings:

```
settings.tokens.start("[[");
settings.tokens.end("]]");
```

Then you could write your template code like this:

```
<h1>[[title]]</h1>
```